# How to reset the rateYo plugin for star rating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, rateyo

I am using rateYo  plugin for star rating in my project. After submitting my boostrap modal which has star rating plugin used, I want to reset my form values as well as stars to be reset. Basically I want to reset the star rating plugin whenever user closes the modal
Below is my code JS code for initializing the rateYo plugin and resetting the form values after modal dismiss.

```
        $(function () {

var rateYo = $("#rateYo").rateYo({
    fullStar: true,
    onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
       rating = Math.ceil(rating);
       $('#rating_input').val(rating);//setting up rating value to hidden field
    }
  });
});

    $('#saveFeedbackBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

var name = $("#name_txt_modal").val();
var rating = $("#rating_input").val();
var topic = $("#topic_sel_modal").val();
var comments = $("#comment_txt_modal").val();
if(name == "") {
  $('#feedbackmodalerrortext').html("Please enter your Name");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else if(rating == "") {
      $('#feedbackmodalerrortext').html("Please select a rating");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }  else if(topic == "select") {
      $('#feedbackmodalerrortext').html("Please select a topic");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
  else if(comments == "") {
      $('#feedbackmodalerrortext').html("Please enter comments");
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
      }
       $('#messageFB').append('');
       $('#feedbackmodalerrortext').html("");
  $.ajax({
        url : "feedbackData.htm?name="+name+"&ratingId="+rating+"&topicId="+topic+"&comment="+comments,
        type: "POST",
        async : false,
        data : "html",
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#messageFB').html('');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.debug(response);
            if (response == "success") {
                $('#messageFB').html('Feedback Saved successfully!');
                $('#messageFB').show();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#messageFB').fadeOut(function(){
                        $('#messageFB').hide();
                    });
                }, 1000);

            } else {
                $('#messageFB').html('Error Saving Feedback data!');
                $('#messageFB').show();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#messageFB').fadeOut(function(){
                        $('#messageFB').hide();
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }

        }     

  });
 });


   $('#myfeedbackModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $rateYo.rateYo("option", "rating", 0);  /resetting star rating plugin
  $(this)
    .find("input,textarea,select,span")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end()
   .find("#rateYo").val('')
  .end()
  .find("feedbackmodalerrortext").val('')
  .end();

    })
```

Comment: Can you please tell us, what exact error is coming when resetting? Please check your browser console for that

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan He's asking how, not having any errors. 

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: rateYo.rateYo is not a function  getting this error

Comment: @MSV Did you put the library before your JavaScript? The rateYo should be loaded before this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$("#rateYo").rateYo("option", "rating", "0");`

You can find detail option on official link [here](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)

Comment: Dude, that's what I answered. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Dude there is difference between the method option, Please check

Comment: As per the documentation, it looks like setting the rating should be done this way: `$rateYo.rateYo("rating", rating);`. Am I missing something?

Comment: What you are doing is the initialisation, this has to be done after initialisation. ☺️

Comment: check the `setter` method [here](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)
Something like this on official page
 `// Setter
$("#rateYo").rateYo("option", "starWidth", "40px"); //returns a jQuery Element`

Comment: Search for `/* set rating */` in the page. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar may be, but it is working at my local demo code

Comment: That definitely works bro. But you are reinitialising.

Comment: guys, you can use either `$rateYo.rateYo("rating", 0);` or `$rateYo.rateYo("option", "rating", 0);` both do the same thing, and there is not difference. Its not initialisation  @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 2):

You can set the rating to `0` to technically "reset". As per the [documentation](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/#method-rating), you can do:

```
$("#rateYo").rateYo("rating", 0);
```